# cy.contains match with regex?

Tags: cypress

I am trying to match part of a url http://www.mywebsite.com/get-stuff in cypress and haven't been able to figure out how to code a regex match.

I tried:
cy.contains('http.*get-stuff') 
and don't find a match for
[do some things](http://www.mywebsite.com/get-stuff)

Comment: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains.html#Arguments

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If you are trying to see if some content on your website has the text `http://www.mywebsite.com/get-stuff` using regex, you will need to pass in a valid [Regular Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). Your argument is attempting to match using a [glob expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)).

If you are trying to see if the url of your website *is navigated to* `http://www.mywebsite.com/get-stuff`, you likely want to write an assertion off of the [`cy.url()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/url.html#Syntax) command like so:

```
cy.url().should('match', /myregexp/)
```

Answer (score 11):

This solution should work too:

```
cy.get('div')                // select DOM element (tag, class or id)
  .invoke('text')            // check the innerHTML text
  .should('match', /regex/)  // compare with a regular expression
```

More on:
https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/invoke

Comment: this helped me because with a `div` you need the `text` prop and so need the `invoke()`

Answer (score 7):

I know it's been quite a long, but for those who are still looking for a solution ( just like me ), you can make use of `cy.url().should('contain', /regex/)` if the accepted solution didn't work for you.