# How to verify a result is in a GUID format in Cypress test?

Tags: regex, cypress, contains

In my Cypress tests, I need to verify that a value is in a GUID format.

Here's an example of the value returned: ***fbb4f73c-0e3b-4fda-ad0a-81a1b8a8c72f***

I've tried asserting using a RegEx below:

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString,
            "(?im)^[{(]?[0-9A-F]{8}[-]?(?:[0-9A-F]{4}[-]?){3}[0-9A-F]{12}[)}]?$",
            "'$0'");

        expect(myXhr.response.body.Id).should('contain', /resultString/)
```

But I get the following error message:

> Invalid Chai property: should

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49140751/3832970). Guid validation regex is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040707/c-sharp-regex-for-guid).

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew for the above links. I've tried to add this to my test, but I'm getting an error now. I've updated my question with this code & error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `.match` to compare your value against a RegEx. You can check the [Cypress Assertions](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/assertions#BDD-Assertions) Page for all the assertions that cypress supports.

```
expect(myXhr.response.body.Id).to.match(/^[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[1-5][0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12}$/i)
```

Comment: Does this work in JavaScript? I'm getting `Regex is not defined` error message

Comment: Yes, it works in JS. Try by directly using the Regex value inside Match.

Comment: Getting this error now `Invalid regular expression: /(?im)^[{(]?[0-9A-F]{8}[-]?(?:[0-9A-F]{4}[-]?){3}[0-9A-F]{12}[)}]?$/: Invalid group (45:45)`. I'll check if the regex is incorrect

Comment: Yes I think there is some issue with the regex. I have used this in my tests against a regex and it works.

Comment: So your assertion works as expected with this new regex pattern: `/^[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[1-5][0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12}$/i`.

Answer (score 1):

You might find it easier to use the [chai-uuid](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-uuid/) library.

Cypress adds it to the build, but I think there's a bug that prevents it being used out of the box. You can however extend chai - see the example recipe [extending-cypress__chai-assertions](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/blob/master/examples/extending-cypress__chai-assertions/cypress/support/index.js) for full info.

Simplest approach is

```
npm install -D chai-uuid
```

or

```
yarn add -D chai-uuid
```

then the test

```js
chai.use(require('chai-uuid'));

it('validates my uuid', () => {

  expect('fbb4f73c-0e3b-4fda-ad0a-81a1b8a8c72f').to.be.a.guid()
  expect('fbb4f73c-0e3b-4fda-ad0a-81a1b8a8c72f').to.be.a.uuid()
  expect('fbb4f73c-0e3b-4fda-ad0a-81a1b8a8c72f').to.be.a.uuid('v4')

  cy.wrap('fbb4f73c-0e3b-4fda-ad0a-81a1b8a8c72f')
    .should('be.a.guid')                          

  cy.wrap('fbb4f73c-0e3b-4fda-ad0a-81a1b8a8c72f')
    .should('be.a.uuid', 'v4')                       // same as 'be.a.guid'

})
```